# Verse that says we should spend much or most of our money on food?

Tags: diet

I remember reading a verse that said something to the effect of it being good to spend much or most of our money on food. What is that verse?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [verse identification](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4199/wheres-the-line-with-the-verse-identification-tag/4200#4200), which is not on-topic here. We're not here to search books for others.  You can do that yourself using google, or searching any of the free online Bibles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isaiah 55 says:

> “Come, all you who are thirsty,
>       come to the waters;
>   and you who have no money,
>       come, buy and eat!
>   Come, buy wine and milk
>       without money and without cost.
>   **2 Why do spend money on what is not bread,
>       and your labor on what does not satisfy?**
>   Listen, listen to me, and eat what is good,
>       and you will delight in the richest of fare.
>   3 Give ear and come to me;
>       listen, that you may live.
>   I will make an everlasting covenant with you,
>       my faithful love promised to David.

It isn't a command, it is an observation. The Messiah that is coming will satisfy the poor and you more than you ever could.

The closest thing to an injunction would be 1 Timothy 6:

> 6 But godliness with contentment is great gain. 7 For we brought nothing into the world, and we can take nothing out of it. 8 But if we have food and clothing, we will be content with that.

Again, the focus is on the contentment, not the actual spending though.

Comment: It's probably the closest to what is being asked.